# How to work with cached Entity Framework data

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, caching

I'm currently working with Entity Framework and have the following scenario to manage, however because a lot happens behind the scenes, I'm not entirely sure what the best route would be, and Googling hasn't provided the necessary answers so far.

I have about 100 products in a product/supplier style database. There are about 10 tables that are used multiple times on each page - due to widgets etc.

I currently cache the results (these 100 products), plus other core entities, in order to carry out approx 80% of the queries I need.

However, from time to time I need to access extended data. Let's say product features - they only appear on a product page - so could be accessed as needed rather than permanently cached. Here are my thoughts out loud, I would appreciate any comments and advice.

1. The easy, but probably worst answer would be to put them in cache too along with the original entity. Although the data wouldn't be too unwieldly, it would have a significant impact on the cached data size.

   - 100 products x 10 features - suddenly becomes 1000. Does this become
     inefficient very quickly?
2. I could query my cached object for the product I need, then reattach to the database. I'm unsure of the mechanics behind this given I'm starting with a cached entity, and it could get pretty messy, very quickly.
3. I could query just the product I need, complete with all additional data on demand. This would involve querying quite a few tables, but only involve a single product, 10 product detail lines, 10 feature rows etc.

All comments and advice appreciated.

Comment: Caching EF entity is not a good idea. EF entity is owned by DbContext and DbContext should have short-life. Also it will leads to `SELECT n+1` problem.

Comment: I output the data to a list and cache that. The context is disposed of at that point.

Answer (score 0):

When I cache values, I always use [AsNoTracking()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery.asnotracking.aspx) to detach those values from the EF context.

The question about how many information you should cache depends on the access frequency and the cost to retrieve the information if it is not there. I'm usually using the caching methods provided by .NET or Azure because they keep track of memory consumption and cause entries to be unloaded if not accessed for a long time. a slightly [old article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx#aspnet-cachingtechniquesbestpract_topic4) on msdn explains the ASP.NET caching mechanism quite good.

I usually use an [abstract class](https://gist.github.com/steven-r/9b26489874a5db285ce8) to hide the caching details, and a concrete implementation for the particular type:

```
public sealed class CustomerIdCache : AbstractCache<CustomerIdCache, Customer>
{

    private CustomerIdCache()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override TimeSpan GetExpiration()
    {
        return new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="db"></param>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
    protected override Customer GetSingleElement(ITimeJackContext db, object[] key)
    {
        Guid id = (Guid)key[0];
        Customer customer = db.Customers.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        return customer;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entry"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetKey(Customer entry)
    {
        return new object[] { entry.Id };
    }
```

Usage:

1. Retrieve information from cache (will be loaded from db if not there)

   ```
   Guid CustomerID = ...;
   Customer customer = CustomerIdCache.Instance.Get(Db, new[] { (object)CustomerId });
   ```
2. Invalidate cache information after updating the database

   ```
   CustomerIdCache.Instance.Invalidate(customer);
   ```